# How to check filesize in Java without reading the file from an UNC Path?

Tags: java, filesize, mirth

I wonder how to check the file-size in Java without opening or reading the file via UNC Path from two different Microsoft Server?
It is for an Interface Engine Filter Function. So no HTML DOM etc. is available.

What works so right now:
There is an Util Function from the API

```
java.nio.file.Files.size(java.nio.file.Paths.get('/path/to/file')
```

which does not work on UNC PATHS due an Error:

```
Wrapped java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: \\server\folder\file.pdf
```

Example for use:

```
var filePath = msg['path'].toString();
try{
    var fileContent = java.nio.file.Files.size(java.nio.file.Paths.get(filePath));
    var fileSize = fileContent / 1048576;
    logger.debug("Filesize in MB: " + fileSize);
}
catch(e){
...
```

Expect: A way to read the file size out file attribute via UNC access

Comment: The documentation you link is for a Java API not a JavaScript one.

Comment: yes, you are right. but the connectors are written in javascript

Comment: You need to update your question to reflect you are trying to get the size of a file on a remote share via UNC path. The javascript tag should be removed as there is not a pure javascript solution for this in mozilla rhino (which mirth uses.) You need a Java solution (which is probably a duplicate question) and converting to mirth javascript is trivial and outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: Does your mirth service user have permission to the share and file you are trying to access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know the file path, you always may use *java.io.File.length()* to return the length, in bytes, of the file. I.e.:

```
var filePath = msg['path'].toString();
// Validate that the filePath is indeed a file and it exists
var fileSize = Packages.java.io.File(filePath).length();
```

Comment: i've solved it with: 
`var filePath = msg['pfad'].toString(); 
var fileContent = java.nio.file.Files.size(java.nio.file.Paths.get(filePath));`

and could wrap it into a try try...catch statement but now I get:  
`Wrapped java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: \\server\folder\file.pdf`

Comment: I mentioned in the following forum post that the answer I gave you was for local files, and UNC pathname support only works on Windows. The share will be accessed as the user you are running the mirth service as, and obviously that user will need access to the path.  https://www.mirthcorp.com/community/forums/showthread.php?p=268827#post268827

Comment: While both solutions work, the java.nio.file packages give much better exceptions when it doesn't.